# How to access the literal text which is inside panel1 and panel1 is inside Datalist1?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

I wanna access the literal1 text which is placed inside panel 1 and panel1 is placed inside datalist1 ...

i wanna retrieve literal1 text on page load event using VB.NET

Comment: What is literal1? A label? A textbox? Something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like...

```
((Literal)((Panel)DataList2.FindControl("YourPanelId")).FindControl("yourLiteralControlId")).Text
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd bind to the **ItemDataBound** event and use **FindControl** to retrieve the literal1.
This link can help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35we4t61(v=vs.85).aspx

Gtz,
Stéphane.